# Set data to object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I've got a problem and I don't know how to get further.

I have something like this.

```
function Paginator() {
    this.currentPage = 1;
};

Paginator.prototype.getCurrentPage = function() {
        return this.currentPage;
};

Paginator.prototype.getNextPage = function () {
    this.currentPage++;
    return this.getCurrentPage();
};

Paginator.prototype.getPreviousPage = function () {
    this.currentPage--;
    return this.getCurrentPage();
};

Paginator.prototype.setCurrentPage = function (page) {
    this.currentPage = page;
    return this.getCurrentPage();
};

Paginator.prototype.renderPage = function (page, data) {
    this.currentPage = page;
    this.pageList = [];
    for(i = 0; i < Math.ceil(75/12); i++)
    {
        this.pageList.push([i, (i-1)*12, i*12]);
    }
    for(i=this.pageList[page][1]; i < this.pageList[page][2]; i++) {
        var tmpl = "<article class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 video'><div class='video-image'><img class='img-responsive img' src='img/" + data[i].image + ".jpeg'><img class='player img-responsive' src='img/icon.png' width='75px' height='75px'></div><p class='video-title'><strong>" + data[i].title + "</strong></p><p class='video-timestamp'>" + data[i].timestamp + "</p></article>";
        $(".video-container").append(tmpl);
    }
};
```

This is my paginator object.

When I call paginator.getCurrentPage(); it will return 1, because that's the default value.

But, if I call renderPage(3, data); it should render the page 3 with data for page 3, and its working. Problem is that this render function is called in another function that is a callback for an ajax function:

```
Loader.prototype.load = function (url, callback, from, to) {
    //load JSON from url
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var self = this;

    xhr.onreadystatechange = ensureReadiness.bind(self);

    function ensureReadiness() {
        if (xhr.readyState < 4) {
            return;
        }
        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            return;
        }
        // all is well
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            var JSONObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            (to) == "all" ? to = JSONObject.length : to;
            callback(JSONObject, from, to);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send('');
};

Cache.prototype.load = function(data, from, to) {
    this.data = data;
    paginator.renderPage(3, data);

};
```

Everything is working, it loads the right data and display them, but on the bottom of the script I have:

```
cache = new Cache();

paginator = new Paginator();

loader = new Loader();
loader.load("http://academy.tutoky.com/api/json.php",cache.load.bind(cache), 0, 30);
```

This should call the loader.load function that calls cache.load function that calls paginator.renderPage function that create view, but also it should set the paginator.currentPage to some value from argument of renderPage function. It does in the scope of the paginator.renderPage function, but when I add console.log(paginator.getCurrentPage()); to the bottom of whole script it will return 1, not the value from the page argument.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/plunker?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4fv32ndz/

Comment: Is it simply because, with the server request being async, the console.writeline is actually happening before the page number is updated?

Comment: Just tried, works well and returns 3. You may have error in other places.

Comment: From your fiddle, console actually logs `5`

Comment: The fiddle has the most important bit commented out, took me a while to figure out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is down to the async call not completing before you're logging the page number.  I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fv32ndz/2/) to wrap the console.log in a callback like so:

```
loader.load("http://academy.tutoky.com/api/json.php",test, 0, 30);

function test(data, from, to) {
    cache.load(data, from, to);
    console.log(paginator.getCurrentPage());
}
```

Obviously, you might want to have a look at improving my naming! ;o)